# I have an unordered list of images, and I want to know which image was clicked (react)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I have an unordered list of images, and I want to know which image was clicked

is there a way to do it without jquery?

```
<div
    {this.props.icons.map((icon) => {
        return (
           <ul>
              <li>
                <img src={icon.url} alt=""></img>
                <p>{icon.name}</p>
              </li>
           </ul>
        )
    })}
</div>
```

This icons array is an array of objects

```
    icons: [{
            id: 0,
            name: 'no-icon',
            url: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/door-hanger.png'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'bungee',
            url: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/bungee-jumping.png'
        },
…..
```

I tried several things, but I deleted them since any of them worked

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: What are things you tried ? And what was the issue that you were facing

Comment: Couldn't you use an onClick handler for each ```img``` since the event that gets passed into your handler will identify which node it was that triggered the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `icon.id`, only left to add `onClick` event:

```
<ul>
  {this.props.icons.map((icon) => {
    return (
      <li key={icon.id} onClick={() => console.log(icon.id)}>
        <img src={icon.url} alt=""></img>
        <p>{icon.name}</p>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul
```